# Let the endomorphism $f$ be given by $f: \mathbb{R^3}\to \mathbb{R^3}, a \to \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 2\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 3 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \cdot a$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, fixed-point-theorems

Let the endomorphism $f$ be given by $f: \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^3}, a \to \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
3 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \cdot a$.

Find a basis for Fix($f$).

---

So we need to solve

$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
3 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}  \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{pmatrix}$

This gives

$\begin{pmatrix}
x + y + 2z \\
y \\
3x + z
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{pmatrix}$

Using the third equation $3x + z = z$, we get $3x = 0 \implies x = 0$.

Using the first equation $x + y + 2z = x$, we get $y + 2z = 0 \implies y = -2z$. So we have $\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
-2z \\
z
\end{pmatrix} = z \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
-2 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}$

So a basis for Fix($f$) would be $\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
-2 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}$. Is that correct ?

Comment: should be correct

Comment: To check if it's fixed multiply it through and see if it changes or not.

Comment: @psl2Z Thank you! Can you or CyclotomicField post an answer so I can accept it ? So the question doesn't appear in the unanswered section anymore

Comment: @CyclotomicField It does in fact change nothing when multiplying, so it should be correct. Thank you ! Can you or psl2Z  post an answer so I can accept it ? So the question doesn't appear in the unanswered section anymore

Comment: @wengen you did the work so feel free to answer it yourself! :)

Comment: @CyclotomicField The thing is on this website you can only accept your own answer two days after you post the answer, and you also don’t earn any reputation.